# How do you get a company's name changed on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs, companies-page

I currently work for Royal Mail however when I enter it into my bio it comes up as royal mail.

Not a major issue but it's been bugging me for a while that it is all lower case.